# XML to Oracle database column mapping

Tags: c#, xml, oracle, mapping, xsd

I am working on xml messages that we get. I have to read the xml and store in 4 different tables.

What is the best way to handle this. Lets say if the xml schema is changed, then new column maybe added or a column maybe dropped or renamed etc...

How can we make this loose coupling. Any changes to XML or database does not require code change?

Thanks,

Comment: how do you use the xml after its stored in the db?  Simply for auditing purposes?  Do you really parse the xml and store relationally?

Comment: @tbone. We read XML from Tibco EMS. Then first store the xml message in a clob field. Later we retrieve the XML and parse it and have to extract values from XML and store in 4 different tables.

Comment: We are planning to do XPath mapping with database column name and table name. But in C# how can we achieve extensibility where future changes to the XML or database don't require don't code change. And also in the future we might need to parse different XML i.e. from other XML providers. We might get XML of different schema from more than 1 provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how you intend to use the XML once stored in Oracle, but if just storing for auditing purposes, you can store XML in a CLOB field along with a version number and some dates.  In a separate reference table, relate the xml version number with its dtd (and created/modified dates).

Comment: We read XML from Tibco EMS. Then first store the xml message in a clob field. Later we retrieve the XML and parse it and have to extract values from XML and store in 4 different tables.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Oracle 11G you can create XMLTYPE variables
in a PL/SQL procedure and You can then use the extract() function to 
retrieve only the parts of the XML document that you want to be fields.

After declaring a PL/SQL variable of type XMLTYPE,
use the XMLTYPE.CREATEXML( ) function to create an XMLTYPE variable.

```
V_INPUT_XML  := XMLTYPE.CREATEXML(V_TAB.INPUT_MESSAGE);
```

The extract() PL/SQL function returns an XMLTYPE and I have 
used getclobval() to convert an XMLTYPE to a VARCHAR.

```
--V_OUTPUT_XML is set by a result of the extract() function 
--on an XMLTYPE
V_OUTPUT_STR := v_output_xml.getclobval();
```

At least with this, you only have to change your PL/SQL if the
path to the fields you're setting changes; changes to the
XML document outside of the fields (as long as they don't
affect the XPATH to the fields) shouldn't require changes to the
PL/SQL..

Comment: @A B currently our database is 10g. Planning for 11g but not sure when that will happen. We are planning to do parsing in C# (LINQ to XML) instead of Oracle XML features.